# Mono write in standard error

Tags: .net, mono

I'm trying to write some error messages in the standard error but it seems that this doesn't work under Mono 3.0.3 (it does work under Windows .NET). What I do is just:

```
Console.Error.WriteLine("something");
```

when I try to redirect the stderr of my program (I run it wrongly to force it to output an error) I got the message in stdout, instead of redirected to the file I specified. I haven't found anything related to this, so I really don't know if I should do this differently.

Comment: Please include the code where you redirect the output.

Comment: Agh! My fault, the problem is in the scripts (arguments parsing) that I use to run my program in Linux... I'll close this as soon as I'm allowed to.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid processing stdin, stdout and stderr redirections when processing the arguments? The problem I have is that in my script: "  mono myprogram.exe "$@" " is taking into account redirections as arguments in $@.